# Simple DFA simulator in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented

In an effort to learn Java, I have written a simple DFA simulator, where a DFA is emulated using an object with a collection of states and inputs. Inputs can then be passed to the DFA to cause it to switch between the states according to a transition table. I hope to expand it with functions which can execute when a `Transition` occurs in the future.

I'm coming mainly from C#, so tips on how to write idiomatic Java would be appreciated.

**DeterministicFiniteAutomaton.java**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.security.InvalidParameterException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Represents a deterministic finite automaton (DFA), with a set of states and
 * transitions between those states.
 */
public class DeterministicFiniteAutomaton {
    private final String[] states;
    private final String[] inputAlphabet;
    private final String[] acceptingStates;

    /**
     * A HashMap of transitions. A HashMap is used to speed up searching
     * through the table to find the correct transition.
     * Keys are of the form input,currentState.
     */
    private final HashMap<String, Transition> transitions = new HashMap<>();

    private String startState;
    private String currentState;

    /**
     * Constructs a new DFA.
     * 
     * @param states The set of states which the DFA may be in.
     * @param inputAlphabet The set of inputs which may be supplied to the DFA.
     * @param acceptingStates The subset of states which are accepting.
     * @param transitions A list of transitions between states on inputs.
     * @param startState The starting state.
     */
    public DeterministicFiniteAutomaton(String[] states, String[] inputAlphabet,
        String[] acceptingStates, Transition[] transitions, String startState) {
        // Due to transition keys' comma-separated nature, state or input names 
        // may not contain commas

        if (Stream.of(states).anyMatch(x -> x.contains(","))) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException
                ("State names may not contain commas");
        }

        if (Stream.of(inputAlphabet).anyMatch(x -> x.contains(","))) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException
                ("Inputs may not contain commas");
        }

        this.states = states;
        this.inputAlphabet = inputAlphabet;
        this.acceptingStates = acceptingStates;

        this.startState = startState;
        this.currentState = startState;

        for (Transition t : transitions) {
            List<String> statesAsList = Arrays.asList(this.states);
            if (!statesAsList.contains(t.newState)
                || !statesAsList.contains(t.startState)) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException
                    ("Transition refers to state which does not exist");
            }

            if (!Arrays.asList(inputAlphabet).contains(t.input)) {
                throw new InvalidParameterException
                    ("Transition refers to input which does not exist");
            }

            String key = getKeyForTransition(t.input, t.startState);

            this.transitions.put(key, t);   
        }     
    }

    /**
     * Resets the DFA to its starting state.
     * This method returns the object it is called on, so may be chained.
     */
    public DeterministicFiniteAutomaton reset() {
        currentState = startState;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Given a valid input, transitions the DFA to another state according to
     * the transition table.
     * This method returns the object it is called on, so may be chained.
     * @param input The input to the DFA.
     */
    public DeterministicFiniteAutomaton input(String input) {
        // Check that this input is contained within the input alphabet
        if (!Arrays.asList(inputAlphabet).contains(input)) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException
                ("'" + input + "' is not a valid input");
        }

        String key = getKeyForTransition(input, currentState);

        Transition transition = transitions.get(key);
        if (transition == null) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException
                ("No transition found for: " + input);
        }

        currentState = transition.newState;

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the current state of the DFA.
     */
    public String getState() {
        return currentState;
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if the current state is contained within the set of
     * accepting states.
     */
    public boolean isAccepting() {
        return Arrays.asList(acceptingStates).contains(currentState);
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the HashMap key used to look up the transition which should
     * be taken, given the current state and an input.
     */
    private String getKeyForTransition(String input, String state) {
        return input + "," + state;
    }
}
```

**Transition.java**

```
/**
 * Represents a transition between two states based on an input.
 */
public class Transition {
    public final String startState;
    public final String input;
    public final String newState;

    /**
     * Constructs a new transition.
     * @param startState The state to start from.
     * @param input The input on which the transition should trigger.
     * @param newState The state to transition to.s
     */
    public Transition(String startState, String input, String newState) {
        this.startState = startState;
        this.input = input;
        this.newState = newState;
    }
}
```

**Usage example**

```
DeterministicFiniteAutomaton turnstileDfa =
    new DeterministicFiniteAutomaton(
        new String[] { "Locked", "Unlocked" },
        new String[] { "Push", "Coin" },
        new String[] { "Locked" },
        new Transition[] {
            new Transition("Locked", "Push", "Locked"),
            new Transition("Locked", "Coin", "Unlocked"),
            new Transition("Unlocked", "Push", "Locked"),
            new Transition("Unlocked", "Coin", "Unlocked")
        },
        "Locked"
    );

turnstileDfa.input("Coin").input("Push");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> import java.security.InvalidParameterException;
> ```

I'm pretty sure that you actually wanted `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` here :) You do not need to explicitly import that, btw. Types from the `java.lang` package are automatically imported.

> ```
>  * Keys are of the form input,currentState.
> ```

That is somewhat unconventional. Especially given that you claim to implement a **deterministic** automaton, it would make significantly more sense to look up by state and *then* by input.
That should also be accomplishable in constant time (two pointer dereferencings), and not require building a String `input + "," + currentState`.
In addition it's much less prone to errors when the `inputAlphabet` or your `states` can contain the separator char. Consider:

```
inputAlphabet = new String[] { "foo,bar", "foo", "bar" };
states = new String[] { "bar", "bar,bar", "foo" };
```

which is "foo,bar,bar" now? is it `"foo" + "," + "bar,bar"` or `"foo,bar" + "," + "bar"`?

I now see that you do actually check for that in your constructor explicitly. It's good that you found the problem, the solution could use some work though :)

> ```
>  private final HashMap<String, Transition> transitions = new HashMap<>();
> ```

I really like that you've declared your fields `final` wherever possible.
I also like the use of the diamond operator.

As opposed to C#, Java interfaces are not explicitly prefixed with `I`. It is still preferred to use interfaces for members. Accordingly this should be:

```
private final Map<String, Transition> transitions = new HashMap<>();
```

Which reminds me... you should use `private final Map<String, List<Transition>>`, that simplifies the lookup by cutting out the key-aggregation. It additionally better reflects what a DFA really works like.

It also allows you to use a bit more modern features in `input`:

```
public DeterministicFiniteAutomaton input(String input) {
    // input-checks have been performed on transitions. 
    // if no transition matches, the input may not have been in the alphabet
    currentState = transitions.getOrDefault(input, Collections.emptyList())
      .stream()
      .first(t -> t.input.equals(input))
      .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("no transition found for: " + input))
      .newState;
    return this;
}
```

Last but not least: I get that going to Java makes one miss C#'s Properties, but this is not an acceptable coding style in Java.

I can warmly recommend using Project Lombok to take care of autogenerating getters (and if needed setters) for your data holder classes.

Comment: I didn't yet mention that you should consider switching to `Set<String>`  instead of `String[]` for all the fields in DFA...

Comment: Good idea; does doing that have performance benefits too?

Comment: Yes, `contains` is \$\mathcal{O}(\log n)\$ instead of \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$